# Unity Oculus gaze pointer- not activated until first controller interaction

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, gaze-buttons

The gaze pointer in my Unity project has worked fine last few months, but since maybe the new Oculus SDK, the gaze will not show until any controller event is first triggered since app loaded - like press any button, or do a swipe gesture. Once it starts working, I can load any scene and the gaze works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if the controller is removed/unlinked before starting the app?

Comment: Tried that thanks - it had no effect.. When I restart app, and gaze at something, gaze icon does not appear until I press a controller button/do a swipe action. Then it works as normal.